# SQL Server interval numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a very simple table with three columns and the next data:

```
+------+---------+---------+
| Cod  |  Value  |  status |
+------+---------+---------+
| 1    |  1      |  1      |
| 1    |  2      |  1      |
| 1    |  3      |  1      |
| 1    |  4      |  0      |
| 1    |  5      |  0      |
| 1    |  6      |  1      |
| 1    |  7      |  1      |
+------+---------+---------+
```

I need to get the intervals of consecutive numbers each code. The result I seek is:

```
+------+----------------+----------------+---------+
| cod  |  min_val_intv  |  max_val_intv  |  status |
+------+----------------+----------------+---------+
| 1    |  4             |  5             |  0      |
| 1    |  1             |  3             |  1      |
| 1    |  6             |  7             |  1      |
+------+----------------+----------------+---------+
```

My problem isn't getting that result. I've tried using the function min, max and group by:

```
SELECT cod, MIN(Value) AS min_val_intv, MAX(Value) AS max_val_intv, status
FROM test_table
GROUP BY status, cod
```

someone could help me out.

Regards.

Comment: Since the status is same that is `1`, you are getting that result and you are grouping by that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
with tab1 as
(select table1.*,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) -
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY status order by Cod) rn1,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) -
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by value) rn2
from table1)
select cod,min(value) min_val,max(value) max_val,status 
from tab1
group by cod,status,rn1,rn2;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29f77/1)

Comment: Hamidreza, I found a bug from your query, I pass the url so you can verify, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99003/1

Comment: Hi again, i try the new query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d907e/1/0 . But not work correctly because intervals overlap 6-26 when the real intervals are 6-7 and 25-26. Regards

Comment: Unfortunately i can't open the `SQL Fiddle` it seems it got problem.

Comment: Hi Hamidreza, I try to open the SQL Fiddle and now it work. Can you review the problem? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d907e/1/0

Answer (score 0):

With good recommendations of Hamidreza, I've got almost the goal, I put the query to be able to review:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a24c/1)

The Query:

```
with tab1 as
```

(select table1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Cod) - 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY status order by cod, value) rn 
from table1 )

select cod,min(value) min_val,max (value) max_val,status from tab1 group by cod,status,rn;

the result is almost perfect but because I repositioned the records if the change of position as in the following link [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/518f2). The result isn't so correct.

Someone comes up as to solve this?

Regards.